# Diagnose SQL running from Power Shell

Tags: sql-server-2012, powershell-2.0

I am trying to run a SQL from Power Shell(which is on my windows 7 64 bit desktop) and the remote database host is MS SQL Server 2012.

The code is:

```
$Server= ".\DB_HOST_NAME"
$Database = "master"
$UserSqlQuery= $("select count(*) from [master].[sys].[some_table]")

# executes a query and populates the $datatable with the data
function ExecuteSqlQuery ($Server, $Database, $SQLQuery) {
    $Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$Database';trusted_connection=true;" 
    $Connection.Open()
    $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $Command.Connection = $Connection
    $Command.CommandText = $SQLQuery
    $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
    $Datatable.Load($Reader)
    $Connection.Close()
    $Datatable
    return $Datatable
}

# declaration not necessary, but good practice
$resultsDataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$resultsDataTable = ExecuteSqlQuery $Server $Database $UserSqlQuery 

Write-Host "Statistic: " $resultsDataTable
Write-Host "Message: Transaction Delay is " $resultsDataTable.Rows.Count
```

When I run this from Windows PowerShell, I get following errors:

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)" At H:\test2.ps1:11 char:5
>   +     $Connection.Open()
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
>
> Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "ExecuteReader
>   requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current
>   state is closed." At H:\test2.ps1:15 char:5
>   +     $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
>
> Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: dataReader" At H:\test2.ps1:16 char:5
>   +     $Datatable.Load($Reader)
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

So the first error is at `$Connection.Open()` but I don't know anything about power shell to figure out what is wrong. I have tried running the same SQL on the same DB host and it does return a number.

Can I get some help to know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Search this site for *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.  The server was not found*. This is not a PowerShell issue.

Comment: DBA checked and confirmed that TCP/IP is enabled but named pipes are disabled. Could that(named pipes being disabled) be an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
$Server= ".\DB_HOST_NAME"
```

should be:

```
$Server= "DB_HOST_NAME"
```

The specification ".\DB_HOST_NAME" is interpreted as a named instance (DB_HOST_NAME) running on your local box.